# How to setup multiple OSQA instances on a Windows server accessible through IIS?

Tags: apache, iis, osqa

On my Windows server, I will be hosting a few unrelated websites that I would like to add the features of OSQA to.  As such, there will be no shared data between the OSQA instances.

Is it possible to have multiple OSQA instances running off the same database (I'm guessing if it's not supported, some db and script tweaking would be required to ID the requesting site), or alternatively (and probably the simplest), having several OSQA instances running on the same box?

I have taken a look at the [Bitnami OSQA stack](http://bitnami.org/stack/osqa), and this may be the simplest solution.  However, this installs Apache, so I wouldn't want multiple instances of Apache running on my box either.

I would also like to be able to access these instances through IIS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to install different OSQA instances on the same database server but you will need to create different databases (in that database server) for each instance. Unfortunately currently we BitNami) don't support IIS nor multiple OSQA installations on the same Apache server so you will need to do it manually.